# IE9 HTML5 video "play" event not fired on second play

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've built simple HTML5 video player. I'm having trouble with the "play" event not being fired in IE9. Have a look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stimpski/uuah8tq0/2/).

The player has a big play button visible before playback, hidden while playing, visible when video completes.

Below are the three listeners I'm using.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    vid.play();
});

vid.addEventListener("play", function() {
    btn.style.display = "none";
    alert("'play' event fired");
});

vid.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    btn.style.display = "block";
});
```

In IE9 the "play" event isn't being fired for the second and subsequent times the video is played through.

I'm guessing it's either something I don't understand about the "play" HTML5 video event, or some kind of bug in IE9.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An assumption:: I think [paused](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) event remains `false` even when your video ends, so may be try explicitly setting `pause` once your video ends, as:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    vid.play();
});

vid.addEventListener("play", function() {
    btn.style.display = "none";
    alert("'play' event fired");
});

vid.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    if( !this.paused ) this.pause();
    btn.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: Thanks DemoUser. I've noticed Firefox, Chrome, Safari all set the `paused` property to `true` when the video finishes playing, and IE9/10/11 set it to `false`. Who is right regarding the spec? (I've looked at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents) and can't find a definitive answer.)

Comment: @Stimpson see this link::https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810454/html5-video-audio-doesnt-become-paused-after-playback-ends , seems for IE, this is by design that pause state does not get fired on video end..!

Comment: Thanks. What a sad state of affairs.